# Applying multiple functions on every column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say, I have the following dataframe:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], columns=['X','Y'])
```

I want to multiply each column by its mean and range and assign descriptive column names to the newly constructed columns. The output I have in mind:

```
X | X_mean | X_range | Y | Y_mean | Y_range
1 |   3    |   4     | 2 |  8     |   8
3 |   9    |   12    | 4 |  16    |   16
5 |   15   |   20    | 6 |  24    |   24
```

I tried to pass the following function using the .agg method but

```
def mean_range(data):
    Xa = np.mean(data) * data
    Xb = (max(data) - min(data)) * data
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([data, Xa, Xb]).T, columns=['data','Xa','Xb'], index=range(len(data)))
    return df1
df0.agg(mean_range)
df0
```

(i) I don't know how to pass the column names into .agg

(ii) It throws up `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind to add a sample of your original df? Or produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, Wrap it before putting into `agg`. You can use `data.name` to get the series' names.

```
def mean_range(data):
    Xa = np.mean(data) * data
    Xb = (max(data) - min(data)) * data
    n = data.name # Get the series' name
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([data, Xa, Xb]).T, columns=[n, n+"_mean", n+"_range"], index=range(len(data)))
    return df1

df2 = df0.agg([mean_range])
df2.columns = [i[-1] for i in df2.columns]
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    X  X_mean  X_range    Y  Y_mean  Y_range
0  1.0     3.0      4.0  2.0     8.0      8.0
1  3.0     9.0     12.0  4.0    16.0     16.0
2  5.0    15.0     20.0  6.0    24.0     24.0
```

Comment: This does exactly that I wanted. Thank you. I have one question though. What does wrapping a function do? Is it because the function returns multiple columns or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, to do the operation (multiply by column mean and range) you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) using the lambda function

To create X_mean:

```
df0['x_mean'] = df0.apply(lambda z: z['X'] * df0['X'].mean(), axis=1)
```

( Lambda function will multiply the elements of df0['X'] by the mean of df0['X'] )

I just didn't quite get the where you want to get with the range function, but once you understood the method I used, you can easily apply to any other calculations. For example you could do:

```
def calculating_range(data, mean_data, max_data, min_data):

    Xa = np.mean(data) * data
    Xb = (max_data - min_data) * data

    (... do your calculations in here)

    r = Xa - Xb
    return r

df0['Y_range'] = df0.apply(lambda z: calculating_range(z['Y'], 
                                                       df0['Y'].mean(), 
                                                       df0['Y'].max(),
                                                       df0['Y'].min(), axis=1)
```

Note that the argument 'DATA' is are the values in the column df0['Y']. You can define 'N' arguments to pass to the "calculating_range" function.
P.